# Allocator working good except for number 1,2 and 3

Tags: c, malloc, implicit, allocator

I am working on school project and I have came across some sort of weird problem where I am unable to allocate sizes of 1,2 and 3 Bytes. Other numbers work as charm. Where can be problem?

It appears that these 2 lines are somehow causing it:

```
*((int*)p) = -1* size;
*((int*)(p + size)) = newsize;
```

When I use printf on *((int*)p) before second line where i assign new size to next block it shows correct value, but moment i use prinf after that line i get weird numbers..

Code:

```
void* memory_alloc(unsigned int size)
{
    char* p = start; //Pointer to start of array
    while (p != NULL && size != 0)
    {
        int sizee = *((int*)p);
        printf("Sizee: %d\n", sizee);
        if (sizee> 0 && sizee>= size + sizeof(int))
        {
            //If remaining size is greater then size of header
            if (sizee- size > sizeof(int))
            {
                int newsize = sizee- size - sizeof(int);
                printf("Newsize: %d\n", newsize);
                *((int*)p) = -1* size;
                *((int*)(p + size)) = newsize;

                return (void*)(p + sizeof(int));
            }
            //If too small allocate whole rest
            else if (sizee-size<=sizeof(int))
            {
                *((int*)p) = sizee* (-1);
                return (void*)(p + sizeof(int));
            }
            else
                return NULL;
        }
        //If it is allocated move in array , allocated numbers are - that is why *(-1)
        else if (velkost < 0 && p + velkost * (-1) != NULL)
            p = p + velkost * (-1);
        //If block lesser than required size
        else if (sizee < size + sizeof(int) )
            return NULL;

        else
            p = p + sizee;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the code and the problem. What is `start`? What exactly should this do? What happens when you use 1-3? How doesn’t it work? And having e [mcve] would help. (Also why multiply by -1 when you could just use minus?)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I do not think that *-1 would cause it. When I use 1-3 it does allocate first call correctly and assign it pointer but second one no, it assigns weird numbers to it and same exact pointer as to previous malloc call. EDIT: Start is pointer to start of array (My "memory" in which i have to operate)

Comment: Yes @Someprogrammerdude I did but couldn´t figure this out by any way

Comment: It wouldn’t cause it but it makes the code look weird. People will wonder why you chose to do that like there is some specific reason. Also note `p + size` means “memory at address p plus *size times the size of an int*” and not “memory at address p plus size bytes”, if that’s the problem.